# Is breadlike a word? Should it have a hyphen?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation

I'm editing a recipe and one step says that the mixture should resemble a "breadlike dough".

This word looks fine to me but it keeps getting flagged up by spell check. Is it a real word? "Bread-like" looks a bit awkward to me.

Comment: What dictionaries have you checked? What do they say?

Answer (score 3):

The *[-like](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-like?s=t)* suffix is so highly productive in English that it can be used with virtually any noun, at first usually with a hyphen, which with broad usage will eventually disappear. If dictionary programs built into word-processing software attempted to keep up with all of them, their data size would be massive.

The popular site dictionary.com has no listing for *breadlike* (though [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breadlike) does), but that hardly means it's "not a word." Even the [US Army](https://books.google.de/books?id=VwT2l9enTFwC&pg=SL5-PA6&lpg=SL5-PA6&dq=breadlike%20definition&source=bl&ots=GtgK7Bg690&sig=16yaCvQv6s35_r9CtC6zqSLGNpc&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi03bqZgrLZAhWE2KQKHTAlAOk4ChDoATAAegQIERAB) mentions

> [a]ny variety of commercial or homemade bread or breadlike product as rolls, muffins, biscuits and bagels.

There are, however, still those who use a [hyphen](http://ask.metafilter.com/172475/How-can-I-rescue-cookie-dough-that-has-become-a-breadlike-dough):

> I'm trying to make gingerbread dough (using this recipe) but it's turning into a bread-like dough.

Since search engines make no distinction between *breadlike* and *bread-like* — or, unfortunately, *...bread like...* or *...bread, like...* — a quick look can usually give you a rough idea of usage. Otherwise, it's up to you. If *breadlike* is a word you may use again, you can add it to the dictionary so it won't be flagged in the future.